# What mathematical distributions describe better traffic in a mobile network?

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-distributions

If it were to describe the traffic in a mobile phone network, what would be the best mathematical distributions?

It would be more of a combination of distributions? Which distribution would describe better normal traffic and which would describe better high traffic?

I have seen lots of distribution being used in many articles, but I don't have the knowledge to conclude which is better for real life simulations.

Note: I am more interested in the distribution of number of calls in a period of time, for short and long periods of time also.

Comment: The best mathematical distribution for *what*? Number of calls per minute? Number of calls given the hour of the day? Duration of calls?

Comment: I updated the answer in my questions. Thank you for helping making it more relevant.

Comment: I have retagged this question, since "distribution-theory" is about a branch of functional analysis, not probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) sounds about right if you are interested in number of calls over a time period.